# I am trying to convert springmvc jar based project to springmvc maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to convert springmvc jar based  project to springmvc maven project but as I run the project facing an error likeorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Check the spring and hibernate versions you used. sometimes it may be the reason